# remove spaces at the beginning from array

Tags: python

I want to remove whitespace from a array,at the beginning.

This is my code:

```
f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
for i in list(lines):
    w = i[3:]
    w = ', '.join(w.split())
    #print(w)
    #time.sleep(1)
    y = i[2]
    y=int(y)+1
    #print(y)
    c1=np.array([w])
    c1 = [int(i) for i in c1[0].replace(" ", "").split(",")]
    c1=np.array([c1]*3)
    c1=np.transpose(c1)
    a=str(c1).replace("[",'')
    a=str(a).replace("]",'')
    print(a)
```

Input: `<=1 2011 2021 2031`
My Output:

```
2011 2011 2011
 2021 2021 2021
 2031 2031 2031
```

I need:

```
2011 2011 2011
2021 2021 2021
2031 2031 2031
```

I tried the function strip

Comment: `print(a.strip())` ? or for your use-case `print(a.lstrip())`

Comment: What happened when you used `.strip()`? Was there an error message you can share?

Comment: Not really sure this warrants an answer... but you're slicing 1 index too short `w = i[3:]` should be `w = i[4:]`

Comment: after using strip () my result was the same as my ouput

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line before `print(a)`: `a=str(a).replace("\n ",'\n')`. `\n` means new line, so if the first letter in a line is a space, it will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner option is as follows:

```
a = ""
for row in c1:
    a = f'{a}{" ".join(map(str, row))}\n'
```